# PayPal Payout Sandbox Account Problem with Status UNCLAIMED

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, sandbox, payout

I have made call sandbox batch payout API using my sandbox account and added unregistered PayPal user to make batch pay, payout API called, and got the success response, got UNCLAIMED status for particular that email address which was unregistered, I have created sandbox account with that email address but that amount paid by sender not deposited in that account.

Again if calling that payout API with same email param, got paid amount in my account, but first transaction payment amount didn't reflecting, Is sandbox not reflect that amount in sandbox account?